# jQuery Backstretch: next, prev methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

I'm building a site that uses Backstretch (super-handy by the way). I've seen a few examples of having specific elements push to a slide, like so:

```
$("#cheers").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.backstretch('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg');
});
```

But has anyone had any experience with creating back/forward buttons (without having to specify a URL)? Looking in the [source](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch/blob/master/jquery.backstretch.js) `line 252` you'll see a `next` function, but I'm unsure of how to use that, binded with a standard click:

```
$("#cheers").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.backstretch('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/515046/www/cheers.jpg');
});
```

Figured this would be useful as a subtle UI addition. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go!

```
$('#next').click(function(x) {
    x.preventDefault();
    $('body').data('backstretch').next();
});
$('#prev').click(function(x) {
    x.preventDefault();
    $('body').data('backstretch').prev();
});
```